# Is a quotient set the same as a partition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

So I've just started trying to teach myself some topology and im really confused on what a partition is and how it is in any way related to an equivalence relation.

My main confusion however is that of the concept of a quotient set I've read that a quotient set is the set of all equivalence classes of a set namely if $S$ is some set with an equivalence relation $R$

Then is the quotient set $S/R=\{[a]  |  a \in S\} $

My question is how is this quotient set the same as a partition of a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a quotient, each class is a subset of elements related by whatever your relation $R$ is. Those subsets are disjoint and each element of $S$ belongs to one of them. Therefore they form a partition of $S$. To see that they are disjoint, suppose $x\in [a]\cap[b]$ with $a$ and $b$ not related by $R$. Then you would have $xRa$ and $xRb$ and from transitivity $aRb$, a contradiction. It should be clear that each element of $S$ belongs to some class (which could be a singleton).

Comment: A partition of $S$ is by definition a family $\mathscr{P}$ of pairwise disjoint, non-empty subsets of $S$ whose union is $S$. The set of equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on $S$ is exactly that: the equivalence classes are subsets of $S$, they are non-empty and pairwise disjoint, and their union is all of $S$. (You may find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238940/understanding-equivalence-class-equivalence-relation-partition/238948#238948) of some use.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to be acquainted with the https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_on_Equivalence_Relations
and its converse.

Every equivalence relation partitions the set it is on into disjoint subsets. Each of the elements in a given subset is equivalent to all the other elements *in that subset*. They divide the population into "bubbles", if you like.

The set of all these subsets is the **quotient set** induced by that equivalence relation.