# Equivalence relations and Stirling numbers

Tags: equivalence-relations, stirling-numbers

Show that there are $\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{n, k}$ equivalence relations on an n-element set. The numbers Sn,k
are Stirling numbers of the second kind.

I am learning discrete mathematics from different books and I have come across the problem above and I couldn't find a way to prove it.

Comment: There is a bijection bijection between partitions of an $n$-element set and equivalence relations on that set; this should be a familiar fact, but you can review it at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238940/understanding-equivalence-class-equivalence-relation-partition/238948#238948) if necessary. $S_{n,k}$ is the number of partitions of an $n$-element set into $k$ parts; every partition of that set must have $k$ parts for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so summing $S_{n,k}$ over those values of $k$ gives you the total number of partitions of the set.

Answer (score 0):

$S_{n, k}$ is the number of surjections from the set of size $n$ to one of size $k.$ Such a surjection corresponds to an equivalence relation with $k$ classes. I think you can take it from there.