# why the number of Equivalence relations on a set is exactly the same as the number of distinct partitions of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

i was given the solution of a question on Enderton'elements of set theory as below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwiVj.png)

it turns out i cant very understand why partitions has to do anythings to Equivalence relation at all after hour of wondering and searching for the definition.
thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding equivalence class, equivalence relation, partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238940/understanding-equivalence-class-equivalence-relation-partition)

Comment: thank you soooo much!!!! taking a deeper look into,

Comment: thank you sooo much!!! im going to take adeeper look

Comment: In summary, it can be construed to be a side effect of the fact that all equivalence relations are transitive.

Comment: @user2661923 Disagree: all three properties of the equivalence relation are required for this statement to hold.

Comment: @DonThousand Agreed; I was taking the other 2 properties *for granted*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when two sets are the same size, that suggests that there is a bijection between them.

Given a partition, there is an obvious equivalence relation of "two elements are equivalent if they are in the same subset". This satisfies all the requirements of an equivalence relation. Obviously all elements are in the same subset as themselves, so this relation is reflexive. If $x$ is in the same subset as $y$, then $y$ is in the same subset as $x$, so it is symmetric. If $x$ and $y$ are in the same subset, and $y$ and $z$ are in the same subset, then $x$ and $z$ are in the same subset, so it is transitive (since all the subsets are disjoint, whatever subset we found $x$ and $y$ has to be the same subset as the one we found $y$ and $z$ in).

So that is a function from partitions to equivalence relations. And it has an inverse: given an equivalence relation, construct a partition such that two elements are in the same subset if and only if they are equivalent.

So this is a bijection between partitions and equivalence relations.